# PHP: Get max value from multidimensional array and get array with max value back

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small problem.
I have no idea what to do this:

Input Data:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => "Food",
        'wish_number' => 10,
        'price' => 1327242001.0,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => "Humanitary",
        'wish_number' => 13,
        'price' => 112459000.0,
    ]
];
```

**What I need:**

I need return array with max(wish_number) key value. If there is 2 or more arrays with the same wish_number i need to choose array with highest price.

Thanks so much guys. You're awesome.

Comment: Did you want someone to write this for you? Or did you want to share what you have tried and have us help you with it?

Comment: You might find [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine example

```
        usort($data, $this->usort_callback);
        $arr = array_slice($data, 0, 1);
  public function usort_callback($a, $b)
  {
        if ($a['wish_number'] == $b['wish_number']) {
            if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) {
                return ($a['last_added'] > $b['last_added']) ? -1 : 1;
            }else{
                return ($a['price'] > $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }

        return ( $a['wish_number'] > $b['wish_number'] ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `array_multisort()` for this task. Example:

```
$wish_number = array_map(function($col){
    return $col['wish_number'];
}, $data);

$price = array_map(function($col){
    return $col['price'];
}, $data);

array_multisort($data, SORT_DESC, $wish_number, SORT_DESC, $price);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

$max = $data[0];
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PeeP8g)